# What does line is supposed to mean?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, floating-point

```
float sqrt_approx(float z) {
    int val_int = *(int*)&z; /* Same bits, but as an int */
    /*
     * To justify the following code, prove that
     *
     * ((((val_int / 2^m) - b) / 2) + b) * 2^m = ((val_int - 2^m) / 2) + ((b + 1) / 2) * 2^m)
     *
     * where
     *
     * b = exponent bias
     * m = number of mantissa bits
     *
     * .
     */

    val_int -= 1 << 23; /* Subtract 2^m. */
    val_int >>= 1; /* Divide by 2. */
    val_int += 1 << 29; /* Add ((b + 1) / 2) * 2^m. */

    return *(float*)&val_int; /* Interpret again as float */
}
```

I was reading a wiki article on methods of computing square root. I came to this code and starred at this line.

```
 int val_int = *(int*)&z; /* Same bits, but as an int */
```

Why are they casting z to an int pointer then dereference it? Why not directly say `val_int = z;`
Why use pointers at all? PS: I'm beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called *type punning*. This particular usage violates [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/1553090) rules

By taking the address of the float value z, and reinterpreting it as the address of an integer value, the author is trying to get access to in-memory bytes representing this float but in the convenience of a `int`.

It's not the same as int val_int = z; which would convert the float value to an integer, resulting in different bits in memory.

A big problem here, apart from the strict aliasing issue, is that the code makes assumptions about the size of `int` on any target system *and* the endianness.  As a result, the code is not portable.

The correct way to access the bytes of `z` is as `char` array:

```
const uint8_t* zb = (const uint8_t*)&z;
```

You could then construct an appropriately-sized integer from these with the a specific endianness:

```
uint32_t int_val = ((uint32_t)zb[0]) |
                   (((uint32_t)zb[1]) << 8) |
                   (((uint32_t)zb[2]) << 16) |
                   (((uint32_t)zb[3]) << 24);
```

This is similar to a simpler call, assuming you are on a little-endian system:

```
uint32_t int_val;
memcpy(&int_val, &z, sizeof(int_val));
```

But this isn't the full picture because `float` endianness is standardized (at least, assuming [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) which your code is targeting) whereas `int` is system-dependent.

At this point, the whole example breaks down.  At the fundamental level the original code is a (supposedly) fast approximation based on tricks.  If you want to do these tricks "correctly", it becomes a bit of a mess.

Comment: Since `zb` is `const char *`, `zb[i]` may be negative. Then converting it to `uint32_t` will wrap, producing 1s in the high 24 bits, which ruins the value being constructed.

Comment: Yes, I had realized this just after posting and added extra casts.

Comment: Just make `zb` `const unsigned char *` in the first place. But even this is not suitable to the situation: This code hard-codes the endianness, making a worse assumption than the original code. The original code worked with big endian or little endian, as long as `int` and `float` had the same endianness. A simple `memcpy(&val_int, &z, sizeof val_int);` suffices.

Comment: Ahh fair point.  I think I confused myself along the way.  Normally when dealing with bits I always work with char.  However, using `memcpy` still breaks down because `float` endianness is not necessarily the same as `int`.

Answer (score 3):

What happens is that the line `int val_int = *(int*)&z` reinterprets the float's bits as integers or rather bitfield and operate on sign, mantissa, and exponent directly of the floating point number directly instead of relying on the processors' operations.

`int val_int = z` would apply conversion from float to int - a completely different operation.

Generally, such operations are ill advised as in different platforms there might be different conventions on interpretation and location of mantissa, exponent and sign. Also `int` may be of a different size. Also, most surely native operations are more efficient and reliable.